# .net sql query compare datetime and change activeBit

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an MSSQL table like below.

[image: ms slq table firstly]

I have an asp.net web method that needs to compare dates and leave the lastest dates active bit as "1", and override others as "0" like the table below.

[image: ms slq table lastly]

Could you help me with how to call that in the asp.net environment to do that? Thank you.

Note that: As IDE side, I use SQL Management Studio and Visual Studio at the local computer as IDE side.

Solution thank to FireyFlames:

**Update my_table Set active = 0 where active = 1 and not ((dateTime) in (select max (dateTime) from my_table))**

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the return query to do this logic:
--Get the latest datetime and store it in a variable
DECLARE @LATEST_DATE DATETIME
SET @LATEST_DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATETIME) FROM TABLE)T

--Return the selected column using case statement
SELECT
A
,B
,C
, CASE WHEN DATETIME=@LATEST_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AKTIVEBIT
,DATETIME
FROM TABLE

Comment: Could you give c# code?

Comment: Thank you for response. I couldnt make your answer to work but this query worked for me: thank you. UPDATE [dbo].[my_table]
   SET [active] = 0 WHERE active= 1 AND NOT  ((dateTime) IN (SELECT MAX(dateTime) FROM my_table))